# Getting Empty user after Facebook login in ParseAndroid

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-android-sdk

I am using Parse Android SDK for my application

I am using the following code for Facebook login

Even it is the new user or old user, Else block is always executed. All I am getting is Empty User (object id is null).

I did following checklist
1. I wiped out all data from my backend
2. I created new Facebook Application with bebug Hash Key
3. I used the same Facebok Application ID in my code 
4. I ensured whether the debuggable=true is set in Androidmanifest

Can anyone help in this ?

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(Arrays.asList(Constants.EMAIL, Permissions.Friends.ABOUT_ME), activity, new LogInCallback()        
        {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) 
            {

                if(err!=null)
                {
                  err.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (user == null)
                {
                    errorClosure.callback(null);
                }
                else if (user.isNew())      
                {
                    Log.e("user.isNew", user.getObjectId()+"");
                    //ParseFacebookUtils.link(user, Arrays.asList(Constants.EMAIL, Permissions.Friends.ABOUT_ME),activity, new OnParseUserSaveCallBack(user, successClosure));
                }
                else    
                {
                    Log.e("Object IDDDDDDDDD", user.getObjectId()+"");
                    successClosure.callback(null);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

ParseUser with null values after a Facebook login is currently a bug of the Parse SDK >= 1.5.0. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/229876443869758/

Do you have the Local Datastore enabled, too? A workaround is to disable it, until an official fix is released.

EDIT: Also, have you checked if `ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication()` is called on the Activity? In other words, you should ovverride the onActivityResult() method this way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: I am not using the new feature local Datastore. I called finishAuthentication() in my Activity. still i am getting the Empty User after Facebook Login. any suggentions how to overcome this.

Comment: It also should be mentioned that the finishAuthentication() should be called inside the onActivityResult of the android **Activity**, _NOT_ the android **Fragment** being used in the Activity.

The distinction has to be made because if you use the standard Facebook SDK (without Parse) for login, they recommend that you use a Fragment.

Comment: Now in Parse-1.9.1 it's `ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Answer (score 0):

Getting this error consistently on Android 4.2. I found one workaround but it's only works for API 19+ as part of my signout I call `ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()` which purges the local file(s) that are causing the parse SDK issue. Now the user can now sign in again with facebook fine.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
                    logger.debug("yay we're on 19+ clearApplicationUserData");
                    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)CMeApp.get().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    am.clearApplicationUserData();
}
```